# Visual Basic code works but is inelegant - any suggestions?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, forms, visual-studio

I am trying to stay ahead of my Year 12 Software class. Starting to work with records and arrays. I have answered the question, but the solution feels very clunky. I am hoping someone has suggestions/links for completing this task in a more efficient way.
The task: read in lines from a text file and into a structure, and then loop through that, populating four list boxes if an animal hasn't been vaccinated.
Here's the code:

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
    'Set up the variables - customer record, total pets not vaccinated, total records in the file, and a streamreader for the file.
    Structure PetsRecord
        Dim custName As String
        Dim address As String
        Dim petType As String
        Dim vacced As String
    End Structure
    Dim totNotVac As Integer
    Dim totalRecCount As Integer
    Dim PetFile As IO.StreamReader

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnLoad_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLoad.Click

        'set an array of records to store each record as it comes in. Limitation: you need to know how many records in the file. Set the array at 15 to allow for adding more in later.
        Dim PetArray(15) As PetsRecord
        'variables that let me read in a line and split it into sections.
        Dim lineoftext As String
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim arytextfile() As String
        'tell them what text file to read
        PetFile = New IO.StreamReader("patients.txt")
        totNotVac = 0

        Try
            totalRecCount = 0
            ' read each line in and split the lines into fields for the records. Then assign the fields from the array. Finally, reset the array and loop.
            Do Until PetFile.Peek = -1
                'read in a line of text 
                lineoftext = PetFile.ReadLine()
                'split that line into bits separated by commas. these will go into the array.
                arytextfile = lineoftext.Split(",")
                'dunno whether this is the best way to do it, but stick the array bits into the record, and then clear the array to start again.
                PetArray(totalRecCount).custName = arytextfile(0)
                PetArray(totalRecCount).address = arytextfile(1)
                PetArray(totalRecCount).petType = arytextfile(2)
                PetArray(totalRecCount).vacced = arytextfile(3)

                totalRecCount += 1
                Array.Clear(arytextfile, 0, arytextfile.Length)
            Loop

            For i = 0 To PetArray.GetUpperBound(0)

                If PetArray(i).vacced = "No" Then
                    lstVaccinated.Items.Add(PetArray(i).vacced)
                    lstCustomer.Items.Add(PetArray(i).custName)
                    lstAddress.Items.Add(PetArray(i).address)
                    lstPetType.Items.Add(PetArray(i).petType)

                    totNotVac += 1
                    lblVacTotal.Text = "The total number of unvaccinated animals is " & CStr(totNotVac)
                End If

            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Something went wrong with the file")
        End Try
        PetFile.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Close()

    End Sub
End Class
```

And one line from the patient.txt file:

```
    Richard Gere,16 Sunset Blvd,Gerbil,No
```

I hope this isn't out of place.

Regards,

Damian

Comment: That's not what this site is for. There are [other sites](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) that are for code review.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there's no actual problem to solve.

Comment: Inelegant is one of those words that is in the eye of the beholder, what is elegant to one person might not be to another.  I do have one comment you can consider, why are you calling "Array.Clear" on arytextfile when the array gets re-assigned via Split as the 2nd line of code in the do loop?  It seems like a needless step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Streams be aware that they need to be disposed.

`File.ReadAllLines` returns an array of lines. Since the array is initialized where it is declared we don't need to specify a size.

If you use `List(Of T)` you do not have to know in advance the number of elements in the list. Avoids the limitation of array.

Using a `For Each` avoids having to use the size. The small `c` following `","` tells the compiler that this is a `Char` which is what `.Split` is expecting. If you had Option Strict On, which you always should, you would have seen an error. You add items to the list by creating a `New PetsRecord`. The parametrized `Sub New` receives the values and sets the properties.

Don't change the display in the label on each iteration. Use an interpolated string (preceded by a `$`) which allows embedded variables surrounded by braces `{ }`. It is not necessary to change the number to a string as it is implied by the interpolator. (Available in VS2015 and later)

```
Public Structure PetsRecord
    Public Property custName As String
    Public Property address As String
    Public Property petType As String
    Public Property vacced As String
    Public Sub New(name As String, add As String, pType As String, vac As String)
        custName = name
        address = add
        petType = pType
        vacced = vac
    End Sub
End Structure

Private Sub btnLoad_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLoad.Click
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines("patients.txt")
    Dim lstPet As New List(Of PetsRecord)
    For Each line In lines
        Dim splits = line.Split(","c)
        lstPet.Add(New PetsRecord(splits(0), splits(1), splits(2), splits(3)))
    Next
    Dim totNotVac As Integer
    For Each pet In lstPet
        If pet.vacced = "No" Then
            lstVaccinated.Items.Add(pet.vacced)
            lstCustomer.Items.Add(pet.custName)
            lstAddress.Items.Add(pet.address)
            lstPetType.Items.Add(pet.petType)
            totNotVac += 1
        End If
    Next
    lblVacTotal.Text = $"The total number of unvaccinated animals is {totNotVac}"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the 'PetsRecord' array to store data, take a look at the following code:

```
Dim totNotVac As Integer
Private Sub btnLoad_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLoad.Click
    File.ReadAllLines("your text file path").ToList().ForEach(Sub(x)
                                                          lstVaccinated.Items.Add(x.Split(","c)(0))
                                                          lstCustomer.Items.Add(x.Split(","c)(1))
                                                          lstAddress.Items.Add(x.Split(","c)(2))
                                                          lstPetType.Items.Add(x.Split(","c)(3))
                                                          totNotVac += 1
                                                      End Sub)
    lblVacTotal.Text = "The total number of unvaccinated animals is " & CStr(totNotVac)
End Sub
```

Comment: Very elegant and concise but without explanation not too helpful to an obvious beginner.